# Why does LVM not provide the function of recursive creation?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, devices, luks

I tries to recursively create LVM on LVM but it seemed unable to provide this function. The way I did is like:

Firstly, I created a physical volume and a volume group on a physical device by

```
$ vgcreate vgtest /dev/sda
Physical volume "/dev/sda" successfully created.
Volume group "vgtest" successfully created
```

Secondly, I created a logical volume on the created `vgtest` by

```
$ lvcreate -n lvtest -L 1G vgtest
Logical volume "lvtest" created.
```

Then, I tried to create a LVM onto the logical volume `lvtest` and it showed failed information:

```
$ vgcreate vgtest_recursive /dev/vgtest/lvtest
Cannot use /dev/vgtest/lvtest: device is an LV
```

We can use LVM to create a volume only on a device, which is inconsistent with what luks does: luks can be used to create a file and even other device on any file. Now, if I intend to create LVM within another LVM in a recursive manner, I need to utilize luks between the two layers of LVM.

What's the rationale behind LVM's design choice? It appears to align with a fundamental Linux principle: "Everything is a file."

Comment: Before create second VG create from LV a PV.

Comment: It would show "Cannot use /dev/vgtest/lvtest: device is an LV"

Comment: So you can't. But what can be reason to want something like?

Comment: I just wonder the reasoning behind such design of LVM. It should treat everything as a file

Comment: It is designers decision. Some old OS (like Solaris 8) can do such things via SVM to make for example RAID10 volumes

Comment: "Everything is a file." is *not* a Linux principle. Several things on Linux are not files.

Comment: I see, such as network interface

Answer (score 4):

Working with "nested" LVM is by default disabled. If you want to create a VG inside a VG you first need to enable `scan_lvs` in the [LVM config](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/lvm.conf.5.html). Configurations like these are usually used with virtualization (LVs are used as backing block devices for the guest system) so you generally don't want to work with these VGs to avoid conflicts between the host and guest LVM tools. The comment for the `scan_lvs` property in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` explains this further:

```
    # Configuration option devices/scan_lvs.
    # Scan LVM LVs for layered PVs, allowing LVs to be used as PVs.
    # When 1, LVM will detect PVs layered on LVs, and caution must be
    # taken to avoid a host accessing a layered VG that may not belong
    # to it, e.g. from a guest image. This generally requires excluding
    # the LVs with device filters. Also, when this setting is enabled,
    # every LVM command will scan every active LV on the system (unless
    # filtered), which can cause performance problems on systems with
    # many active LVs. When this setting is 0, LVM will not detect or
    # use PVs that exist on LVs, and will not allow a PV to be created on
    # an LV. The LVs are ignored using a built in device filter that
    # identifies and excludes LVs.
    # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
    # scan_lvs = 0
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response, as it has been incredibly helpful to me. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're misunderstanding the design of LVM: a volume group is composed of physical volumes. Which is something you can create on any block device. So you need a `pvcreate` on your `lvtest` before you can create a VG containing it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I convinced that I didn’t misunderstand LVM. In cases where no Physical Volume (PV) has been initialized on the target drive, `pvcreate` can be automatically triggered by `vgcreate`. However, the key point is that we are unable to employ `pvcreate` on a Logical Volume (LV) or a regular file.